# CSS: Fixed header table - how to not focus on the out-of-view row behind the fixed header when scrolled up?

Tags: javascript, css, html-table, fixed-header-tables

### Background

I have a table with fixed header (fixed `<th>`s to be exact), with vertically scrollable content. You just scroll up and down with the scroll bar as usual, and you can scroll up and down with up/down arrow keys. I am highlighting where is the currently focused row with a red outline. See for yourself below.

### Problem

The problem is when scroll down a bit and try to go up with `up` arrow key, it reaches the top row under the fixed header. the top row is not visible, so focusing on that when scrolling up with `up` key is not favorable.

### Question

How do I prevent focusing on a "out-of-view" row? Ideally I want it to scroll further up if it reaches the top last visible row, not the one behind the fixed header. Maybe I should do something with the header?

### Minimum reproducible code

Here is [the JSFiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/uzbeki/17odtrqs/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set `container.scrollTop = 0` to programmatically scroll to very top. Code adapted to your case:

```
    case 38: // up
        currentRow?.previousElementSibling?.focus();
        // check if we've reached the first <tr />
        // if so, set container.scrollTop = 0
        if (!currentRow?.previousElementSibling?.previousElementSibling) {
            e.target.closest(".table").scrollTop = 0;
        }
        break;
```